# Load and fit Form into a Panel

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a windows Form based program. I have created a main form with menu buttons at bottom and a Panel above it to fill the rest of the Form. And I load another form into that panel from menu button. But when load From to panel the Form is lot bigger than the panel and I can only see a part of my Form. Can someone help me please?

here is my codes

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim f As New Form2
        f.TopLevel = False
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        f.Visible = True
        Panel1.Controls.Add(f)    
    End Sub
```

This how it looks. There is more buttons and controls below.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

And I tried these codes. but nothing changed.

```
    f.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(980, 600)
    f.AutoSize = True
    f.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

Comment: `f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill` should do the trick _on its own_. If that doesn't work for you, please [edit] the question and provide a [repro].

Comment: I started a new project. Tried that codes. but same results. I am a beginner for vb.net can you help me with this. What should I do? @41686d6564

Comment: Please edit your code to show a more complete picture.  The problem isn't shown, or not completely revealed yet.

Comment: If the Panel's content can be larger than the Panel's ClientArea, you of course need the Panel to Scroll, so set it to AutoScroll. Don't dock the Form. -- Using a Form is a bad idea. In this scenario, you should use a head-less TabControl and add your Controls to its TabPages.